# Jupyter Notebook becomes unresponsive after inactivity for a while, does not log to terminal

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

This is a strange thing that I've noticed only for a particular computer. If I leave the Jupyter Notebook page inactive for a while (without closing the browser page or putting the computer to sleep) and come back to it, the kernel would appear to be completely unresponsive; but it wouldn't say "Kernel Dead" either. Restarting the kernel from the Jupyter Notebook does nothing so I always ended up having to close the command window from which Jupyter Notebook was run, and it goes without saying that all the variables were lost.

Whenever this happens, any activity on the Jupyter Notebook page following its "death" is not logged in the command window that runs it.

Tried searching around on GitHub which might have been a more appropriate channel with no luck. 
I'd be happy to provide more info. Thanks!

Comment: Could it be your OS or browser managing memory & idle threads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This wight not be a helpful answer as it will not address the root cause of the problem but rather present a workaround. The kernel is an independent process from the browser so you can close the browser tab and reopen it (e.g http://localhost:8888/) and it connects to the still running kernel without any problems.